# Removing a navigation property doesn't update the database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have 2 POCO classes (below) and wish to remove the link between two of their records.  According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) EF 5.0 should be able to handle the removal without loading the User class like so:

```
context.Computers.Find("test").User = null;
context.SaveChanges();
```

This doesn't work, but using the .net 4 approved method it works:

```
en = context.Computers.Find("test");
context.Entry(en).Reference(e => e.User).Load();
en.User = null;
context.SaveChanges();
```

My EF reference is EntityFramework.dll version 5.0.0.0.  Am I missing something obvious here?

Here are the classes:

```
public class Computer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Computer> Computers { get; set; }
}
```

Edit:  Here is the specific lines in the above linked article that don't seem to agree with the functionality I'm seeing:

To delete the relationship, set the navigation property to null. If you are working with the Entity Framework that is based on .NET 4.0, then the related end needs to be loaded before you set it to null. For example:

```
context.Entry(course).Reference(c => c.Department).Load();
course.Department = null;
```

Starting with the Entity Framework 5.0, that is based on .NET 4.5, you can set the relationship to null without loading the related end.

Comment: Don't you mean `context.Computers` instead of `context.Users` and `...Find("test").UserId = null;` instead of `...Find("test").User = null;`?

Comment: Yes on the Users (i've made the update).  For ...Find("test").User = null; is correct.  I'm setting the navigation property to null in order to unlink the User from the computer.

Comment: Did you disable lazy loading or proxy creation? Your first line relies on lazy loading to be enabled, otherwise it won't work. But with lazy loading it will load the `User` - in contrast to your expectation. If you don't want that, set the `UserId` to `null`.

Comment: @Slauma LazyLoadingEnabled and ProxyCreationEnabled are both set to true.  I'm not concerned with loading `User` and updating `UserId` instead does work but being able to remove relationships through navigation properties would be much easier, especially for composite key relationships.

Comment: Did you check if `context.Computers.Find("test").User` is **not** `null` before you set it to `null`? If so, the update should actually work in my opinion.

Comment: Yes.  Oddly enough, if I step over the line setting `User` to `null` it works.  When breaking on `context.SaveChanges();` `User` is untouched

Comment: @Slauma In addition, it seems that it only works after I look at the `User` property through a breakpoint or in code.

Comment: Ah, I see. You call the property getter of `User` when you inspect the property in code or in the debugger. This triggers lazy loading. But your first line above only calls the property setter, so no lazy loading occurs. Anyway, I would suggest to use eager loading `context.Computers.Include("User").SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == "test").User = null;` which should work and will save you one database roundtrip.

Comment: @Slauma Looks like it works!  So to sum up, the MSDN article I linked is a bunch of hooey, at least in the section `Starting with the Entity Framework 5.0, that is based on .NET 4.5, you can set the relationship to null without loading the related end.`?

Comment: Hm, interesting, I have no idea what they mean exactly. Maybe put that quote at the beginning of your question, perhaps someone knows how it is supposed to work.

Comment: @Jake - this is correct. If lazy loading is enabled it is impossible what null means (and if you read it to check it will try loading the related entity) but if you explicitly set a navigation property to null (even if it was null before) it should remove the relationship.

Comment: @Pawel I don't understand what you mean by "it is impossible what null means", could you clarify?  As for setting the navigation property to null before loading, that is what I'm doing but the relationship still exists after the save (the Computer's UserId remains unchanged).

Comment: @Jake - sorry it was supposed to be "it is impossible *to know* what null means". If lazy loading is enabled the property value may be null because it has not been loaded or there is not relation and you cannot distinguish between the two. I believe in .NET Framework 4.5 it was changed so that setting such a property explicitly to null will break the relationship in the case where the relationship existed but the related entity was not loaded. Does this work in your case if you load the entity and then set it to null?

Comment: @Pawel Explicitly setting the property to null before it's loaded (ex: `en = context.Computers.Find("test"); en.User = null;`) just doesn't update `en.UserId` after save.  As of now it seems that EF 5.0 doesn't work as advertised.

Comment: @Jake - I got some time to look at it - your entities are not change tracking proxies. This works if they are. See my response with a sample code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't see the relationship being deleted since your proxy is not a change tracking proxy but lazy loading proxy only. To make it a change tracking proxy you need to set all the properties to be virtual. Below please find an example that resets a navigation property without loading it first. Now a question is whether or not to use change tracking proxies - see [this post](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/12/05/should-you-use-entity-framework-change-tracking-proxies/) as it contains an interesting discussion on this.

```
public class Computer
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Computer> Computers { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Computer> Computers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } 
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyContext())
        {
            if (!ctx.Computers.Any())
            {
                var user = ctx.Users.Add(new User());
                ctx.Computers.Add(new Computer() { Id = "MyComputer", User = user });
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        using (var ctx = new MyContext())
        {
            var computer = ctx.Computers.Single();
            computer.User = null;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var ctx = new MyContext())
        {
            var computer = ctx.Computers.Include("User").Single();
            Console.WriteLine(computer.User == null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha! Thanks for clarification. Is this a new behaviour in EF5/.NET4.5 and didn't this work with .NET 4.0? The article linked in the question says so, but is actually using a model without change tracking proxies.

Comment: @pawel Are you sure this is new? I thought this has been in since EF 4.1.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor For pre-EF6 versions proxies are generated inside System.Data.Entity.dll and not inside EntityFramework.dll . Since the .NET Framework 4.5 was an in-place update you can see this light up in EF4.1 if you use EF4.1 on a box with .NET Framework 4.5. In short - it depends on the .NET Framework on the box and not on the OOB (out of band) version of the EntityFramework.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

I just read through the comments (i probably should have read them first but i already wrote this so ill leave it) and see you guys came to a pretty similar conclusion, hopefully this still helps explain a bit of the why. Also on a side note I think that you are better off to use the FK id property to null the relationship if its available as this means you wont have to actually load the remote entity at all.

---

Hey so i think this is whats going on:

You loading your Computer entity

- at this point the User navigation property is null
- The tracking graph has the initial state of this entity set to null

You set the User property to null

- the tracking graph is still set to null so cant tell the difference between your intentional null and the not-loaded-yet null

You save changes

- The tracker examines the initial graph, sees you havent loaded the user property yet and treats null as unloaded initial state
- no changes are persisted

If this is the case as i see it there are two different ways you can make EF detect this as a change (and hence delete your relationship):

1. Force loading of the user *before* setting the relationship to null, you can do this either by accessing it as you have lazy loading enabled, or using the .Include syntax in your query.
2. Set the UserId property to null instead

The second is far easier and should work as the user ID property isn't on a remote entity. EF will treat either a null nav property or a null FK as a change and perform a delete.